# change format values of the axis plots in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, format, decimal, axis

I'm new in matplotlib, and I want change the value's format of the axis x, like this:

Axis x : 250000, 500000, etc. Change to the format 0.250, 0.500, etc.

What can I do for this point?

Thanks

Comment: I would like to invite you to read [ask] and [mcve] and stick to those guides when asking a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would usually just scale the data prior to plotting. So instead of `plt.plot(x,y)`, you'd use `plt.plot(x,y/1e6)`.

To format the values with 3 decimal places, use a `matplotlib.ticker.StrMethodFormatter` and supply a format with 3 decimals, in this case `"{x:.3f}"`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)

x = np.arange(5)
y = np.array([5e5,2e5,0,3e5,4e5])

plt.plot(x,y/1e6)

plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.StrMethodFormatter("{x:.3f}"))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, i did with: 
def numfmt(x, pos): # your custom formatter function: divide by 100.0
    s = '{}'.format(x / 1000000.0)
    return s ; and xfmt = tkr.FuncFormatter(numfmt)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)